# Where are the built-in components such as EditForm documented?

Tags: blazor

I don't seem to see a list of the default Blazor components in the docs.  Anyone got a link that lists them and gives their properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I'd suggest you use the following:](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/master/src/Components/Forms/src)

[And this:](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/master/src/Components/Web/src/Forms)

This is the place you should consult when coding

Answer (score 3):

- Usage is described here: [ASP.NET Core Blazor forms and validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61785787/where-are-the-built-in-components-such-as-editform-documented)
- Classes are documented here: [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms?view=aspnetcore-3.1)